# Given roots (real and complex), find the polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

This is not a duplicate of [theory of equations finding roots from given polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614222/theory-of-equations-finding-roots-from-given-polynomial).

Given that the roots (both real and complex) of a polynomial are $\frac{2}{3}$, $-1$, $3+\sqrt2i$, and $3+\sqrt2i$, find the polynomial. All coefficients of the polynomial are real integer values.

What I have so far: $$(3x-2)(x+1)(x-\sqrt2\times i)=0$$ If I were solving other similar problems with two complex roots, I would probably be able to cancel them out, but I'm confused about how to do the $(x-\sqrt2i)$ part. Is this actually two complex roots that meet? Also, what degree is this polynomial? I would like an algebraic explanation please.

Comment: Are you sure you're not being asked for a real polynomial?

Comment: I'll edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: If the coefficients of the polynomial are real, then $3-\sqrt{2}{i}$ is also a solution.

Comment: In the question, there are only 3 roots. Not including $3-\sqrt2i$.

Comment: If the coefficients are real, there is no polynomial whose complete list of roots is as given.

Comment: For a polynomial with real coefficients, the complex solutions come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: @AndréNicolas is absolutely right, Jason. If you insist that the coefficients are real, then we insist that nonreal roots occur only in conjugate pairs.

Comment: Apparently, the book has a typo then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjugate factor theorem states that for a polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients, the complex roots come in conjugate pairs, or if $a+bi$ is a root, then $a-bi$ is also a root. From this we see that your polynomial has the roots $$\frac{2}{3}, -1, 3+\sqrt{2}i, 3-\sqrt{2}i.$$ Therefore, $$(x-\frac{2}{3})(x+1)(x-3-\sqrt{2}i)(x-3+\sqrt{2}i)=0.$$ $$\therefore (x^2+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{2}{3})(x-3-\sqrt{2}i)(x-3+\sqrt{2}i)=0$$ $$\therefore (x^2+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{2}{3})(x^2-6x+11)=0.$$ Continuing the expansion results in the polynomial $$p(x)=\frac{1}{3}(3x^4-17x^3+25x^2+23x-22).$$

Comment: We call it the conjugate factor theorem in Australia, everybody else calls it the complex conjugate root theorem I believe.

Comment: Check it out, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem).

Comment: Also. Whack the polynomial into WolframAlpha and it'll give you roots, showing the polynomial to be correct.

Comment: Would it be better to make the first term $(3x-2)$? Then you would be able to remove the coefficient in front of the final answer.

Comment: Either way works.

Comment: @MitchKnight.You could replace the $1/3$ in front by any non zero integer constant since $p(x)=k(3x^4-17x^3+25x^2+23x-22)$ is the general solution. Cheers :)

Comment: Shouldn't there be a restriction on $k$, namely $k\neq 0$?